# How to use status variable in navigation item in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I would like to show/hide navigation item according to state changes in react native app.
This is what I have done.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {    
    return {
      headerLeft: <Button this.state.showSaveBtn && title='Save'/>
    }
  }
...
validateForm () {
    if (validate()){
       this.setState({showSaveBtn: true});
    } else {
       this.setState({showSaveBtn: false});
    }
}
```

But it can't be run because 'this' don't refer current component.
I have just shown how I would like to do.
What the important is to control navigation item with state variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the navigation State, not the Component State.
If form `validate()` returns true, you can do something like `this.props.navigation.setParams({showSaveBtn: true })` and then in navigationOptions you just need to do something like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

        const { params } = navigation.state;

        return {
          headerLeft: <Button params.showSaveBtn && title='Save'/>
        }

};
```

Ps.: Don't forget to define the default value to `showSaveBtn` navigation parameter in `componentWillMount()`

Answer (score 0):

Change ideas

```
navigationOptions: {
    header: null
}
```

Customize a header